# Unwanted padding on background as more content is added

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a layout for a hotsite but I'm facing certain problems.
At the initial page the background is being correctly placed (image 1), but in another page with a major content it appears with a padding on top (image 2)
If I lower the content, the background back to normal (image 3).

---

My CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1B0807;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url('../img/bg.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

[image: image 1:]

---

[image: image 2:]

---

[image: image 3:]

How to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
background-position:center top;
```